# Running out of Disk space during table partition

Tags: sql-server-2008, partitioning

I'm trying to parition a large table (**160Gb**). It contains data from `IIS logs` that have been generated over the **last 70 days**. The partition Scheme and function split the table into the relevant day.

There is one file in each file group and one days data goes into each file.

There is no clustered index currently on the table, there are 2 Non clustered indexes around the time the log was created and the ASP Session ID that has been pulled from the data.

The issue I am having is when I try to assign this table to be partitioned I'm running out of disk space.

Is there a way of batching the process?

```
USE [Diagnostic_MB]
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_Scheme70Day_634883295513235207] ON [dbo].[IISLog] 
(
    [SentUTCDateTime]
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [Scheme70Day]([SentUTCDateTime])


DROP INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_Scheme70Day_634883295513235207] ON [dbo].[IISLog] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ASPSession] ON [dbo].[IISLog] 
(
    [ASPSessionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [Scheme70Day]([SentUTCDateTime])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Time] ON [dbo].[IISLog] 
(
    [SentUTCDateTime] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [csHost],
[scStatus],
[timeTaken]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [Scheme70Day]([SentUTCDateTime])


COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This is the code that ends up eating all my disk space. Ideally I'd like to be able to move the data out of the primary filegroup rather than creating a copy. This isn't a database that needs to be up all the time so `offline solutions are also welcome...`

Comment: Just in case you're wondering why you're getting no response, this question should be asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com/.  I have voted to "close" the question with migration to DBA, but there are currently only 2 votes (5 are needed).

Answer (score 0):

Briefly: when partitioning SQL Server rebuilds clustered index. To rebuild clustered index it sorts all record. Sort happens in tempdb. Server requires free space of the size of the table or may be x2 size the table dependind on the mode (sorry, don't remember right now).

Quick fix: copy some data (=1 target partition) into temp table, create indexes on that table on PF, switch that bit into destination table. Moving 2-3 GB at a time should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Stoleg had a good idea already. Here's another one: drop non-clustered indexes pre-rebuild (because the CI rebuild might rebuild them as well, depends on your situation) and use separate transactions for all operations (a running transaction prevents dropped alloc units from being deallocated and the space released).

There's also a more advanced trick: build a NCI on your partitioning key and the CI key. That way SQL Server potentially uses that NCI to build the partitioned CI. It then does not need to sort the data set again because the NCI provides the sort order. I have actually seen this plan shape in the wild. SQL Server does not always sort the entire table if it can use an NCI in combination with a key lookup. Sometimes the lookup plan is cheaper according to its heuristics.